# WinAPI. Как объединить два HDC или BITMAP в третий HDC?

Tags: winapi

Есть HDCA, которое создается так:

```
HDCA = GetDC(hwnd);
HDCB = CreateCompatibleDC(HDCA);
HBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(HDCA,620, 700);
HGDIOBj = SelectObject(HDCB,HBitmap);
```

Есть ли способ которым можно нарисовать несколько картинок (например разные Bitmap, или разные два HDC в которых нарисовано методом SetPixel)  в один HDC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть такой способ, конечно, и не один. Обычно, правда, не сразу два в один, а сначала копируют один битмэп, а потом накладывают второй. Посмотрите [список функций](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/bitmap-functions), и обратите внимание, в частности, на функции `BitBlt`, `StretchBlt`, `MaskBlt`, и `PlgBlt`.

Самое сложное там разобраться с кодами операций (ROP - raster-operation codes). К сожалению, в доках MS даются только несколько ходовых значений. Правильней все же будет разобраться как они получаются, и научиться создавать свои коды ROP.

Раз уж вы решили углубиться в WinGDI, я вам настоятельно рекомендую почитать книгу Фень Юань "Программирование графики для Windows". Сейчас она доступна для скачивания в виде PDF, найдёте легко, по первой же ссылке в поисковике. Это лучшее руководство по WinGDI, с множеством примеров, и отличным объяснением нетривиальных моментов.

Comment: Все коды операций: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/ternary-raster-operations

Comment: @t3f, я имел в виду символические имена, их как раз немного. А статья эта, конечно, полезная, но начинающему из нее мало что будет понятно. Лучше все же почитать у Фень Юаня.